# Livy session gets corrupted

Tags: apache-spark, livy, mlflow, pystan, facebook-prophet

we are using a **Apache Livy** server to communicate with a spark cluster. We have noticed that some statements when executed error out and afterwards livy session becomes unusable. For example we are using **fbprophet** for timeseries models. **fbprophet** and **pystan** produce some console output. As soon as this output is logged in session the statement gives error. Although the job continues to execute on the cluster. And afterwards no statement runs correctly.
Output after running statement with fbprophet code

`Unrecognized token 'Iter': was expecting 'null', 'true', 'false' or NaN`
`at [Source:     Iter      log prob        ||dx||      ||grad||       alpha      alpha0  # evals  Notes ; line: 1, column: 9]`

Similarly while creating docker image using **mlflow build-docker** command, it also produces output about the image creation process. Again as soon as this output is generated the session errors out
Following is the output for build-docker

``````` Unexpected character ('/' (code 47)): maybe a (non-standard) comment? (not recognized as one since ``````Feature 'ALLOW_COMMENTS' not enabled for parser) ```````
`at [Source: /tmp/tmpq6gz1q3t/; line: 1, column: 2]`

Main issue is that the session becomes unusable after such statements.
Has anyone faced such issues with Apache livy?

One **resolution** that I can think is to suppress the output from pystan and docker processes, But I could not figure that out. How can we suppress the output from being logged into livy session?